# Add custom html after the last child of my list using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use javascript to add a custom div after my last child of a unordered list, the result should basically look like this.

```
<ul class="mylist">
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
 <div>custom div</div>
<ul>
```

I am getting this far, but don't know if it's close to be the right solution.
I cant get it to work

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.getElementByClassName("myList").lastChild.innerHTML = "<h1>test</h1>";
}
```

Comment: this is an invalid html mark up..only LI is child of UL

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you don't want to do that. A `div` as child of `ul` is simply not valid. You could add a new `li` at the end or append something inside the last `li` though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jquery` and append the `div` though this is not a valid markup.<kbd>[append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)</kbd> dynamically add child element.

```js
$(function(){
  //this is valid child of <ul>
  $('.mylist').append('<li>custom content 1</li><li>custom content 2</li>');

  //this is invalid markup but you asked for though
  $('.mylist').append('<div> custom content 1 </div><div> custom content 2</div>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mylist">
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: If you check the HTML output in the DOM inspector you can see how broken the result is. A `div` cannot be a child of a `ul`

Comment: As I said this is not a valid markup though. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Firstly, you just edited it to include that note. Secondly, why not fix it in your answer? This is a broken solution for that reason

Comment: @JanHenriksen Since jquery version 1.4, `append()` function added. Read the jquery apis and version over here. http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4/

Comment: @JanHenriksen what problem do you face when using `append()`?
Did it shows any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Native DOM implementation using `querySelector` and `insertAdjacentHTML` methods

```js
document.querySelector('.mylist > li:last-child')
        .insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<li><h1>Test</h1></li>')
```

```html
<ul class="mylist">
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. querySelector seems to work for me. The append function did not work, could figure out why.

Answer (score -1):

a div as a child of ul is not valid in html for you to insert the div you need to first add list then have the div inside of the list something like this

```
<ul class="mylist">
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
 <li> content </li>
 <li>
     <div>custom div</div>
</li>
<ul>
```

since yyour list child is a list then you script that could either append hence replacing `<div>custom div</div>` with `<h1>test</h1>` should be something like this since we are appending inside of the last li tag

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.getElementByClassName("myList")
 .lastChild.innerHTML = "<h1>test</h1>";
}
```

that way your markup is valid and and test is rendered on browser

Comment: What is `getElementByClassName`? There is `getElement**s**ByClassName` that returns multiple elements wrapped in `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: the last child should always return the one tag in the collection

Comment: Try your code. First of all `document.getElementByClassName("myList")` throws TypeError because there is no such thing as `getElementByClassName`. Even if you fix this typo you get `HTMLCollection` which doesn't have `lastChild` [Spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection)